# RabbitMq replay limitations

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to use rabbitmq for a client requirement. Client suggested rabbit mq. 
Based on some googling it looks like rabbitmq does not support replay of past messages from arbitary offsets unlike say kafka.

I just need a confirmation on whether this limitation is still valid. Any official url will be helpful.

Thanks.

R

Answer (score 2):

> Based on some googling it looks like rabbitmq does not support replay
> of past messages

That's correct. Once a message is delivered and acknowledged (if the queue requires an ack) it is never available again and no trace of it remains in RabbitMQ.